# Dictionary with multiple values per key via for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

given a List in Python I want top create a dictionary that stores all possible two sums as keys and the corresponding indices as values, e.g.

list = [1,0,-1, 0]
Then I would to compute the dictionary {1:{0,1}, {0,3}, 0: {1,3},{0,2}, -1:{1,2}, {2,3}}.

I am having troubles finding out how to have a dictionary where one key corresponds to multiple values. If I use dict[sum]={i,j} I am always replacing the entries in my dictionary while instead I would like to add them.

Does anyone know if there exists a solution?

Comment: For each key, the corresponding value can be a list of 2D-tuples, where each tuple contains the indices. For your example, the result could be { 1:[ (0,1), (0,3) ], 0:[ (1,3), (0,2) ], -1: [ (1,2), (2,3) ] }. This way, for each key you can use the append method to add a tuple of indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use a dictionary with [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to add the results and [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate the combinations of indices:

```
lst = [1,0,-1, 0]

from itertools import combinations

out = {}
for i,j in combinations(range(len(lst)), 2):
    a = lst[i]  # first value
    b = lst[j]  # second value
    S = a+b     # sum of values
    # if the key is missing, add empty list
    # append combination of indices as value
    out.setdefault(S, []).append((i,j))

print(out)
```

Condensed variant:

```
out = {}
for i,j in combinations(range(len(lst)), 2):
    out.setdefault(lst[i]+lst[j], []).append((i,j))
```

output:

```
{ 1: [(0, 1), (0, 3)],
  0: [(0, 2), (1, 3)],
 -1: [(1, 2), (2, 3)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr = [1, 0, -1, 0]

map = {}

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
        s = arr[i] + arr[j]
        if s not in map:
            map[s] = []
        map[s].append((i, j))

print(map)
```